# Binary left and right shift

Tags: binary

There are two questions made me feel confused.

1. What is

   ```
   1101011(2)
   ```

   in 8 bit binary left shifted by 5?
2. What is

   ```
   001010100(2)
   ```

   in 12 bit binary right shifted by 3?

Answer (score 0):

> What is 1101011(2) in 8 bit binary left shifted by 5

you add the 5 digits at the right, so 110101100000 then you limit to 8 digits removing extra bits at the left, so 01100000

> 2). What is 001010100(2) in 12 bit binary right shifted by 3?

you remove 3 digits at the right, so 1010 (or 000000001010)